# Got FileNotFoundException for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Tags: android

I know there are many post on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for finding out folder for saving files. When I used it, I am getting

/storage/emulated/0/myfolder

as folder path and getting below error when try to use for saving file.

w/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myfolder/myfile (No such file or directory)

How to resolve this issue? I would like to use Internal Memory for storing Image & video in the same fashion as other app does.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update : As requested Code for saving Image that is been created.

```
    public String saveTofolder(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

    String stored = null;
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "myfolder");
    if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.flush();
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stored = "success";
    }
    return stored;
}
```

Comment: Add your code for saving the file.

Comment: Show what have you tried... Where are your files located, in internal or external memory?

Comment: @Samirk I am downloading image and saving it in internal memory. I am using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to find folder  path and then creating new folder as a child. Hope this clarifies..

Comment: can you show us the code, how do you make the folder?

Comment: Add code to check if the folder was really created, before you try to write a file to it. Maybe something went wrong while creating the folder.

Comment: Ok will cross check  that and come back but really worry is about 0 being there in folder path /storage/emulated/0/myfolder/myfile. I wanna avoid it. Also just wanna know if getExternalStorageDirectory() is creating folder in internal storage memory or not? Pls advise

Comment: There is no problem with this code running on my emulator. It properly creates a file and the path has a 0 in it. What is actually throwing the exception? Need to see a stack trace.

Comment: In Android Studio you can use the View->Tool Windows->Device File Explorer to see the files and paths on your emulator. Don't forget to right click and "synchronize" after you change the file system.

Comment: @Ves Sounds good. But why 0 is coming? This is bugging me. Can you advise on actual devise at which location Folder will be created?

Comment: The actual path varies from device to device. There is a bunch of information here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files